# Dataframe merge overlapping dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have a question where I need to merge two dataframes whose values(masked) are given as

dds is a dataframe and its data is

```
STATE    START_DATE  END_DATE    data_val
Alabama  04/01/2021  06/15/2021  x
Alabama  06/16/2021  08/12/2021  y
Alabama  08/13/2021  09/30/2021  z
```

ops is another dataframe and its data is

```
STATE    START_DATE  END_DATE    data_val2
Alabama  05/01/2021  31/05/2021  ab
Alabama  06/01/2021  12/01/2021  cd
Alaska   04/01/2021  08/01/2021  ez
```

Now the dataframe needed is:

```
STATE    START_DATE  END_DATE    data_val  data_val2
Alabama  04/01/2021  04/30/2021  x         NULL
Alabama  05/01/2021  05/31/2021  x         ab
Alabama  06/01/2021  06/15/2021  x         cd
Alabama  06/16/2021  08/12/2021  y         cd
Alabama  08/13/2021  09/30/2021  z         cd
Alabama  10/01/2021  12/01/2021  NULL      cd
Alaska   04/01/2021  08/01/2021  NULLL     ez
```

I am new to Pandas and am unsure how to do it. Please help.

Comment: (1) Which library is used (pandas, polars, spark,...)? Set an appropriate tag. (2) Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a typo in the ops dataframe: `31/05/2021` should be `05/31/2021` to be in the `%m/%d/%Y` format.

That being said, what we want to do is three things:

1. Expand the dates from start date & end date to a date range where each row contains a day within this date range.
2. Merge these two (new) dataframes together based on overlapping date (and corresponding state)
3. Groupby the state and values to find the minimum date (start date) and the maximum date (end date) within that group.

The steps can be written as follows:

1. Creating new dataframes:

```
def expand_dates_df(
    df,
    date_format="%m/%d/%Y",
    start_date_col="START_DATE",
    end_date_col="END_DATE",
    data_col_name="data_val",
):
    # Convert the date columns to datetime format
    df[start_date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[start_date_col], format=date_format)
    df[end_date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[end_date_col], format=date_format)

    # Create a new dataframe with daily observations
    expanded_rows = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        date_range = pd.date_range(
            start=row[start_date_col], end=row[end_date_col], freq="D"
        )  # D: Day
        for date in date_range:
            expanded_rows.append(
                {"STATE": row["STATE"], "Date": date, data_col_name: row[data_col_name]}
            )

    expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows)
    return expanded_df

expanded_dds = expand_dates_df(dds)
expanded_ops = expand_dates_df(ops, data_col_name="data_val2")
```

2. Merging the two expanded dfs

```
joined_df = expanded_dds.merge(expanded_ops, how='outer', on=['STATE', 'Date'])
```

3. Grouping the dataframe so the result is as desired

```
joined_df=joined_df.fillna('None')
joined_df.groupby(["STATE", "data_val", "data_val2"])["Date"].agg(
    START_DATE="min", END_DATE="max"
).reset_index().sort_values(["STATE", "START_DATE", "END_DATE"])
```

Result:

```
STATE   data_val    data_val2   START_DATE  END_DATE
Alabama x           None        2021-04-01  2021-04-30
Alabama x           ab          2021-05-01  2021-05-31
Alabama x           cd          2021-06-01  2021-06-15
Alabama y           cd          2021-06-16  2021-08-12
Alabama z           cd          2021-08-13  2021-09-30
Alabama None        cd          2021-10-01  2021-12-01
alaska  None        ez          2021-04-01  2021-08-01
```